# Database Consolidation / AlwaysOn Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

1. How can I calculate the potential savings in RAM, Storage and CPU by consolidating a certain number of servers into single server?
2. How can I go about consolidating the BI servers' and the OLTP servers' databases. Do I have to separate the consolidation of the OLTP servers' databases from that of the BI servers' databases?

The end goal is to put all the databases in one availablility group to create redundancy but adding a replica.

Any suggestions or materials will be highly appreciated.